# Dynamically assign a default value for Postgres column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a nullable column whose values are taken from an enum.
I want to define that column's default value based on another column's value.

For example, given the following table:

```
name | type | status
-----|------|-------
abcd | t1   | null
efg  | t2   | s1
```

The status column is based on an enum and can be nullable.

can I somehow define that the default value of status should be

s1 if type==t1 else null

Postgres version = 13.4

Comment: You need a trigger for that. Default values can not be based on other columns.